# Run script in parallel based on parallelism factor that will be given

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to run shell scripts in parallel based on a parralelism factor that I will give and in case any process get completed at that instant another script will get triggered automatically.
For example parallelism factor=3 and out of 3 scripts 1 got completed then automatically the other should get triggered as long as all get completed and there is none left. Shell script can be given inside a array and can be iterated in a loop.

Comment: Try putting `[gnu-parallel]` in the Search box above.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                               

scripts=("echo V" "echo fgnaq" "echo  jvgu" "echo Hxenvar" "echo Fgbc"
         "echo Ehffvna" "echo ntterffvba" "echo Chgva" "echo vf"
         "echo n" "echo penml" "echo qvpgngbe")
parallel -j3  ::: "${scripts[@]}"
```

If you want to do this without having the GNU Parallel utility installled, you can do:

```
parallel --embed > myscript.sh
```

and append this to `myscript.sh`:

```
scripts=("echo V" "echo fgnaq" "echo  jvgu" "echo Hxenvar" "echo Fgbc"
         "echo Ehffvna" "echo ntterffvba" "echo Chgva" "echo vf"
         "echo n" "echo penml" "echo qvpgngbe")
parallel -j3  ::: "${scripts[@]}"
```

You can then use `myscript.sh` on a machine that does not have GNU Parallel installed.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do programatically without parallel utility.